# how to reload data when there is new data in the database

Tags: jquery

This scripts reloads every 5 seconds, the thing is,i want to reload it, when there is new   data in the database, how can i do that thing?

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
   $("#msgs").html("<img src='images/loading.gif'>");  
   window.setInterval(function(){  
   $.post("view_data.php",  
   {loader:1},  
 function(data){  
    $("#msgs").html(data);  
     });  
},5000);  
});
```

Comment: Run the script when you get new data.

Comment: how can i do that thing, sorry im just a beginner in this PL,

Comment: I was kidding, what you're doing is fine. Since you're dealing with external data, you'd always have to check for something - be it database results, a text file, but there's no way to inject something like that into the client, push method doesn't really work like that. Read about [long polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long%5Fpolling).

Comment: i really want to do that thing ,is there any way to do it?

Comment: i just noticed that my client side is bufferring  whenever the script is running so, my plan is to reload the page when there is  new data in the databse

Answer (score 0):

If you use only JS, you won't be able to do "realtime" another way.

If you have access to your server, you could use nodeJS to handle such events in realtime.

You can alternatively use a service (hosted or not) that enables you to do realtime like Pusher or Firebase.

Here is an exhaustive list of such services : http://www.quora.com/What-are-alternatives-to-pusher-com

Comment: i heard about nodeJS my problem is, i dont understand how it works, i tried to watch video about that but still all my videos that i saw is explaining its feature not on how to create a simple but concrete example to the users who want to learn about that Nodejs